# Do the cookies have their path set to an appropriately restrictive value for the application

Tags: php, cookies, path

As I have searched recently, I found some specific information about domain and path.

**Domain restriction:**

When a website sets a cookie, it is by default tied to the originating domain. For instance, if **server1.cookie-domain.com** set the cookie, the web browser will automatically send the cookie with all subsequent requests to that **domain** and it **sub-domains** (admin.server1.cookie-domain.com).

But the cookie will **not** be sent to the parent domain or peer domains (cookie-domain.com or server2.cookie-domain.com).

**Path restriction:**

If an application residing at **http://cookie-domain.com/app1/index.jsp** sets a cookie, the browser will automatically send this cookie to all requests for pages residing under the `/app1/` directory and also any sub-directories but if those attributes have been set to `$wgCookieDomain = ''` and `$wgCookiePath = '/'`.

**So, my question:** 
Do the cookies have their path set to an appropriately
restrictive value for the application?